# Online tool for saving code snippets

Tags: web-apps, note-taking, source-code

I need an online tool to save code snippets.

Not just for saving, but also having a simple interface to search for the snippets. And maybe download the repository if needed.

I was using Notebark, but it is an offline tool. It has a tree structure and we can create folders and then nodes under it. It also has a search feature to search the entire tree for any keyword existing in the name of the node or its content.

Something similar would be nice.

Comment: Could you explain more about "easy to search/retrieve"?

Comment: Notebark has a tree structure and is similar to the Microsoft Help files. I could create a folder say CSS and then create nodes with specific names under it. We could just browse all nodes under CSS if needed. I could also then type a keyword to search in the entire tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure, someone else has the same question. After trying a few online Apps, I stumbled upon [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) and feel, this is the best so far.

**Pros**

- The interface is very simple.
- It also has a [Desktop Client](https://evernote.com/download/). So you can use this on your PC and
  also via web too. The syncing is pretty fast.
- Organize the snippets by Stacks & Subfolders.
- Option to create MS Word like documents with styling and images.
- If you have a bunch of text files in local drive, it's easy to add
  them all in one go.
- Export all the snippets as HTMLs.

**Cons:**

- When uploading text files from your local drive, the title of the
  snippet is not the name of the text file. You need to rename it.
- If you have maintained a folder structure in Evernote and then export
  as HTMLs. The folder structure is not maintained in the downloaded
  files.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

https://gist.github.com/

There you can create you own snippets, share, favorite, tag, etc...

Comment: I did check that. The site often goes down at login.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend these following web-apps:

1. **TiddlyWiki**

   **[TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)** is a unique non-linear notebook for capturing, organizing and sharing complex information. It has tags and search. So, it makes you easy to organize your code snippets. TiddlyWiki also has many useful plugins. If you want to highlight your syntax, you can use [syntax highlighting](http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Syntax_Highlighting).

   TiddlyWiki is all JavaScript so you can run it locally in your browser. But, if you need a server to [host](http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Server-Side_Solutions) it, you can also do that.
2. **GistBox**

   **[GistBox](http://www.gistboxapp.com/)** is a web application for organizing code snippets. This software relies on your GitHub account. So, in other words, they access your code snippets saved in GitHub Gist. The good thing is this software supports color-coded labels and searching-filtering. Color-coded labels enable you to organize your code snippets by language and soon. Beside that, there are feature-rich code editor, keyboard shortcuts, and collapsible file views.

Comment: I tried GistBox and it's quite good. The interface feels a bit dated Anno 2017, but it's one of the better alternatives I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

I built [SnipSave](https://snipsave.com) because I couldn't find a solution that suited my needs exactly. Adding/editing snippets is quick and intuitive, and the search is fast and searches the title, tags, and code itself of each snippet.

https://snipsave.com

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [3cols](https://www.3cols.com) as it's the only site that isn't slow like gists, offers enough categorisation options and stores all your snippets in the cloud for free. The only thing it charges for is sharing boards and that only costs $1.69 per month